# How to receive data for object within a for-loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a code where I have two object for a class. I want to use the same for-loop to produce sum of loop for each object. How do I do this? Also, I only have the code created for c1, is there a way I can also write it for c2 without redundancy in the code?

I only provided some code from the files where I am having issues with.

**Calorie.java**

```
public void setCalorieSum(int calorieSum) {
    this.calorieSum = calorieSum;
}

public void setMealsAte(int mealsAte) {
    this.mealsAte = mealsAte;
}
```

**CalorieTester.java**

```
Calorie c1 = new Calorie();
Calorie c2 = new Calorie();
int num = 1;

System.out.println("Information for Day #" + num +": ");
c1.setMealsAte(number(console, "\t how many meals did you eat? "));

        for(int j = 1; j < c1.getMealsAte() + 1; j++) {
            c1.setCalorieSum(number(console, "\t how many calories were consumed in meal " + j + "? "));
            int calorieSum += d1.setCalorieSum();
        }

System.out.println("-- Total caloric intake = \n"/* + c1.getCalorieSum + " --"*/);
num++;
```

Comment: Write a method that accepts the Calorie object as a parameter. Then call the method twice.

Comment: Can you please show me?

Comment: Make an attempt and I will help. I'm not writing it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea looks correct. Howver you need to intilize and delcare the int calorieSum before the for loop like:

```
int calorieSum=0
for(int j = 1; j < c1.getMealsAte() + 1; j++) {
            c1.setCalorieSum(number(console, "\t how many calories were consumed in meal " + j + "? "));
            calorieSum += d1.setCalorieSum();
        }
```

Also if I am understanding the purpose of your code right where c1 and c2 are different entities that need to be filled in by the user you can just make the for loop you have created to:

```
int calorieSum1=0;
int calorieSum2=0;

for(int j = 1; j < c1.getMealsAte()+c2.getMealsAte() + 1; j++) {
            if (j<c1.getMealsAte()){
                  c1.setCalorieSum(number(console, "\t how many calories were consumed in meal " + j + "? "));
                  calorieSum1 += d1.getCalorieSum();
             }
           else {
                 c2.setCalorieSum(number(console, "\t how many calories were consumed in meal " + j + "? "));
                 calorieSum2 += d2.getCalorieSum();
                }
        }

}
d1.setCalorieSum(calorieSum1);
d2.setCalorieSum(calorieSum2);
```

And then make 1 getter methods

```
public void getCaloriesSum(){
       return this.calorieSum;
}
```

Comment: This fixed a few things, but line calorieSum += c1.setCalorieSum(); causes a problem because I need an argument in setCaloriSum(); So, my program won't even run. How do I go around this issue?

Comment: Right. So in that line are you trying to set the calorie sum of the object d2 to the counter of calorieSum. I edited the code snipped that should now be error free, based on what I think you are trying to achieve. If its not let me know

Comment: I'm still receiving an error message: "The method setCalorieSum(int) in the type Calorie is not applicable for the arguments 
 ()"

Comment: Can you update your code to the current one, so I can see how you implemented it, to look for the issue that might cause that

Comment: because it sounds like when you called the method, you did not pass the calorieSum1 as a parameter.